# Multiple Docker Images per tag. One per digest

Tags: docker, image, kubernetes, docker-repository

I have a k8s deployment that pulls an image based on the *digest* rather than the *tag*.

Why? I have multiple lower k8s namespaces which all pull from the same Docker repo. I don't want a bug fix for *ns-dv* to accidentally replace with an image pushed for *ns-qa*. So I'd like to keep both images around, even if they share a tag.

And since imagePullPolicy is always, new dynamic pods in *ns-qa* may use the latest, incorrect image.

```
imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Thus, in my Docker repo (Mirantis) I'd like to keep multiple images per tag, one per digest.

Is this possible?

Comment: The tag part of the image name is intended to distinguish image versions the way you're describing.  If the image `ns-dv:20211205` had a critical security bug, then build and push a new image `ns-dv:20220119`.  (I would not normally expect to have different images per environment, and Kubernetes generally expects a Deployment's `image:` value to change as the signal to trigger a redeployment.)

Answer (score 3):

A digest uniquely identifies an image. A tag points to a digest. So, you cannot have multiple images that have the same tag. The difference is, a tag may be updated to point to a different digest. Two different tags can point to the same digest.

So you either have to use the digests, or different tags for each namespace (app-dev, app-qa, etc.). The different tags may point to the same image, or they may point to different images.

When you promote a dev image to qa, for instance, you can simply tag the dev image as qa, so both app-dev and app-qa tags pull the same image. Then you can make updates to the dev image, and tag that as app-dev, so dev namespace updates, but qa namespace stays the same.

Comment: This is very useful. Would you please share a source of documentation where more information can be found. Thanks